# liquibase: automate the author attribute by git's user

Tags: git, liquibase

It is quite annoying to fill up mandatory author attribute for each changeset. 
And we are using git as a CVS. 
Would it be possible somehow automatically fill up that attribute by a git user's name, for each changeset created?

Comment: The purpose of the author field is to record who made the changeset.... Not the person who checked out

Comment: @MarkO'Connor I meant the person who checks in the code with a changeset.

Comment: Try using a GIT pre-commit hook that performs a textual substitution.